# Implementing leave one out cross validation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement LOOCV in python, my code runs fine but my outputs are nan values.
   I tried to use KFold with `n_splits = len(y)` but it returns the same output. I am quite new to python. I would appreciate any help from you guys on this problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
data_ = pd.read_csv("insurance.csv")


 # Create dummies
data_dummies= pd.get_dummies(data_, columns = ['sex','region','smoker'])
print(data_dummies.head())
data_dummies = pd.DataFrame(data_dummies)
data_cleaned = data_dummies.drop(['sex_female','region_southwest','smoker_no'],axis = 'columns')  
# Leave one out CV 
X= data_cleaned.iloc[:,[0,1]]
y= data_cleaned.iloc[:,3]
 #kfold = KFold(n_splits = len(y), shuffle = True, random_state= 0 )
model = LinearRegression()
loo = LeaveOneOut()
scores = cross_val_score(model,X.values,y.values,cv=loo)
print(scores)
#-----------Output--------------
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=len(X), scoring = 'mean_absolute_error')
```

scoring function can be changed according to your purpose.

Comment: It says mean_absolute_error is not a valid scoring value.

Comment: Is not this a regression task? If yes, it would be sklearn version issue. Otherwise (i.e., classification task), change the scoring function. Or, try 'neg_mean_squared_error'.